# Proof of an example of integral inequality

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following problem

$$\int_{t\sqrt{n}}^{\pi\sqrt{n}/2} e^{-\phi^2/2}\mathrm{d}\phi \leq \sqrt{2\pi}e^{-t^2(n+2)/2}$$
where $t\in[0, \pi/2]$.

The numerical analysis shows that the inequality holds true, but I don't know how to prove it. This is related with an example from "High-Dimensional Statistics: A Non-Asymptotic Viewpoint", but the proof is omitted.

Comment: If you want some help, could you at least make the lhs explicit ?

Comment: Yes, I think it is equivalent to prove$$\sqrt{n}\int_{t}^{\pi/2}e^{-ny^2/2}\mathrm{d}y\leq\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-t^2(n+2)/2}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing that $$\int_{t\sqrt{n}}^{\pi\sqrt{n}/2} e^{-\phi^2/2}\mathrm{d}\phi \leq \sqrt{2\pi}e^{-t^2(n+2)/2}$$ means (after integration and simplifying) that we need to show that
$$F(n,t)=2 e^{-\frac{1}{2} (n+2) t^2}+\text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{n} t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{\pi 
   \sqrt{n}}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right) \geq 0$$ Checking at the bounds, it is true since
$$F(n,0)=2-\text{erf}\left(\frac{\pi  \sqrt{n}}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)>0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad F\left(n,\frac{\pi }{2}\right)=2 e^{-\frac{\pi ^2}{8}  (n+2)}>0$$
The first derivative
$$F'(n,t)=e^{-\frac{n+2}{2}  t^2} \left(\sqrt{\frac{2n}{\pi }}  e^{t^2}-2 (n+2) t\right)$$ cancels only once at
$$t_*=\sqrt{-\frac{1}{2} W\left(-\frac{n}{\pi  (n+2)^2}\right)}$$ and the second derivative test shows that this is a maximum.

So, it is true.